# Ruby on Rails only showing what is in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to rails and have developed a simple rails application on my machine that works when hosted locally with WEBrick.

I understand that you need to delete index.html from the public folder and set the proper root in config/routes.rb to point to the controller you wish to be root, which I did with:

```
 root :to => 'home#index'
```

(On the remote host)

When I have the index.html file in the public folder and go to mywebsite.com/myapp I see the page.
When I delete the index.html page from the public folder I get a 404 and my app does not run.

Any idea as to why my app is not running when I deploy it to the remote host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your root to `home#index`, then you need to have a view `app/views/home/index.html.erb`. The corresponding controller method would be `def index`, located in `app/controllers/home_controller.rb`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be app/views/home/index.html.erb ?

Comment: I did that, I tested the app on my machine locally and it worked rendering the page from the respective controllers that I generated.

Comment: When I pushed the app out to the host, (Rails version and gems were all properly matched) I would only see content from the public folder. If I am seeing content from the public folder is it possible that the rails app is not running at all?